# How do I load a model from ember-data into a handlebars.js template?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-data

I have an Ember.js app that gets its data from a JSON resource, and puts it into an ember-data model (Not sure about the terminology) for use in a Handlebars.js view. When I try to put the data into the template context, I get this error:

```
TypeError: arrangedContent.addArrayObserver is not a function
```

I've made a Fiddle to demonstrate it. Use [the actual Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WZ4vt/) to view the code, use the following link to see the error (which makes it try to put data into the template/view):

http://fiddle.jshell.net/WZ4vt/show/#/item/1

```
s = App.store.find(App.Item, 1);
s.get('value1');
```

The above works fine, and returns "test".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WZ4vt/3/

Your mistake was to declare your ItemController as ArrayController, but your Data Store just returned a single entity. I fixed that and additionally your Handlebars Template, as this was not working either.

So this is the new controller declaration:

```
ItemController: Em.Controller.extend(),
```

And the updated Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="item">
    {{content.value1}}
    {{content.value2}}
</script>​
```

Here the working link:  http://fiddle.jshell.net/WZ4vt/3/show/#/item/1